# JS async\await Сделать переменную из полученных результатов асинхронных функций

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Подскажете, пожалуйста как создать массив и заполнить его ответами которые пришли от асинхронных функций.

Вот пример:

```
async function getMultiArr(){
    let multyArr = [];

    const arr1 = getOrganicResults("Тестовая фраза 1").then( (result) => {console.log("arr1 =", result);}).catch( (err) => {console.log(err);});
    const arr2 = getOrganicResults("Тестовая фраза 2").then( (result) => {console.log("arr2 =", result);}).catch( (err) => {console.log(err);});


    const result  = await function(){
        return multyArr.push([arr1, arr2]);
    }

    console.log("result =", result);

    return result;
}
getMultiArr();
```

Не могу понять, что я не так передаю в синтаксисе. Мне нужно вернуть массив по типу

```
multyArr=[ ['Результат из первой асинхронной ф-ции'], ['Результат из второй асинхронной ф-ции'] ]
```

А мне консоль возвращает `result = [Function (anonymous)]`

Comment: `async function getOrganicResults(phrase) { }` Там асинхронные запросы.... Ваш вариант что-то не помог. в консоли result = 1 //// а потом показываются значения console.log("arr1 =");console.log("arr2 =")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> .then( (result) => {console.log("arr1 =", result);})
> ```

Выкинуть или заменить на

```
.then(result => (console.log("arr1 =", result), result))
```

> ```
> const result  = await function(){
>         return multyArr.push([arr1, arr2]);
>     }
> ```

```
const result = await Promise.all([arr1, arr2])
```

И вообще не называть промисы `arr`.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Как правильно называть промисы в таких случаях?

Comment: @BlackStar1991, ну зависит от того, что в них лежит. Может `results` или `organics`. Или вообще никак не называть и сразу совать в следующий вызов. А `arr` вообще так себе имя, а когда в переменной даже не массив, то вообще жесть. Если уж называть бессмысленным именем по типу, то `promise1`, `promise2`. Ну или `organicsPromise1`, но на мой вкус для локальной переменной это слишком длинно.